# change The width of the FastScroll listview

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll

I would like to reduce the width  FastScroll listview.

How at Android Studio i can change The width of the fastScroll listview ?

Does not work
android:scrollbarSize="50dip"

Comment: Does not work android:scrollbarSize="50dip"

Comment: Show your XML which has the `ListView`.

Comment: Also, make sure that "instant run" is disabled. It is still buggy and may be causing problems.